# QRubberBand and MPlayer in QLabel

Tags: qt, transparent, qlabel, mplayer

I have already tried many solution that are provided on stackoverflow to make it transparent.
I want to make QRubberBand transparent and i am also facing problem regarding that green color which is due to mplayer.

```
   #include "physician.h"
   #include "ui_physician.h"

    Physician::Physician(QWidget *parent) :
         QMainWindow(parent),
         ui(new Ui::Physician)
    {
         ui->setupUi(this);
         ui->sendROIButton->setStyleSheet(
                    "background-color: #d9d9d9;"
                    "border-radius: 10px;"
                    "color: Black; "
                    "font-size: 15px;"
         );
     }

     Physician::~Physician()
     {
         delete ui;
     }

     void Physician::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
     {
         rubberBand->hide();
         bottomRight = e->pos();
         QRect rect = QRect(topLeft, bottomRight).normalized();
         rubberBand->setGeometry(rect);//Area Bounding
         QToolTip::showText(e->globalPos(), QString("%1,%2")
        .arg(rubberBand->size().width())
        .arg(rubberBand->size().height()), this);
      }
      void Physician::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
      {
        wWidth=ui->videoShowLabel->width();
        wHeight = ui->videoShowLabel->height();
        rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 0, 0).normalized());
        rubberBand->hide();
        topLeft = e->pos();
       }
       void Physician::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e){
        rubberBand->show();
       }

       void Physician::on_manualROIRadioButton_clicked()
       {
         rubberBand = new QRubberBand(QRubberBand::Rectangle, this);
       }

       void Physician::on_autoROIRadioButton_clicked()
       {
         QString winNuber= QString::number((int)(ui->videoShowLabel->winId()));
         QStringList argsList ;
         argsList << "-slave" << "-quiet" << "-wid" << winNuber << "zoom" << "-
         vo" << "gl" << "C:/../../../Physician21/PhotoshopQML.mkv";
         mplayer_proc = new QProcess;
         mplayer_proc-
         >start("C:/../../../PhysicianTest/mplayer/mplayer.exe",argsList);
        }
```

Comment: http://imgur.com/tUYSOdk

Comment: http://imgur.com/2gnndL3

Comment: I also want to make that this QRubberBand should work only on that QLabel in which mplayer is embedded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, regarding "QRubberBand should work only on that QLabel".  You need to make the `QLabel` the parent of the `QRubberBand` to achieve that.

Secondly, regarding transparency I assume you mean that the output from mplayer should be visible through the rectangle painted by the `QRubberBand`?  I'm not sure you will be able to do that.  Doing so would required the rubber band painting logic to act as a compositor but in order to do that it needs to know both the source and destination(mplayer) images.  Since mplayer draws directly on the underlying native window `Qt` has know knowledge of the current destination image and so can not merge the source image with it.  I think your best bet would be to find/generate a style that causes `QRubberBand` to draw the rectangle outline only -- not sure if that's possible.  You could subclass it and do your own painting with something like...

```
class rubber_band: public QRubberBand {
  using super = QRubberBand;
public:
  template<typename... Types>
  explicit rubber_band (const Types &... args)
    : super(args...)
    {}
protected:
  virtual void paintEvent (QPaintEvent *event) override
    {
      QPainter painter(this);
      painter.setPen(Qt::red);
      painter.setBrush(Qt::NoBrush);
      painter.drawRect(rect().adjusted(0, 0, -1, -1));
    }
};
```

The above could still leave visual artifacts on the widget though.

Comment: can you help how to remove that green color??

Comment: I can't really comment on the green edges without knowing precisely which widget is affected (is it the same widget whose window id is passed to mplayer?).  One suggestion might be to try a different `-vo` option.  Do "mplayer -vo help" at a command line and try a few of the available options.

Comment: i appreciate your answer atleast you try to help me(yes it was the same widget that was affected whose id was passed to mplayer) but due to your suggestion i think that i should play with arguments that i have passed then i removed zoom argument and finally i get rid of that green color.